# Spring integration RabbitMQ - Listener with retry

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Below is my declarative configuration inside xml file for rabbitmq listener. Retry with advic chain doesnot seem to be happening.DLQMessageRecoverer class is throwing RabbitmqRejectAndDontRequeue exception. It doesnot seem to be calling it either.

```
<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="dlqMessageRecoverer"/>
    <!--<property name="messageRecoverer" ref="errorMessageRecoverer"/>-->
    <property name="retryOperations" ref="retryTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="dlqMessageRecoverer" class="com.prosper.phlconsumer.service.error.DLQMessageRecoverer" />

<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="500000" />
            <property name="maxInterval" value="12000000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<rabbit:listener-container id="messageListenerContainer"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="1" acknowledge="auto" advice-chain="retryAdvice" >
    <rabbit:listener ref="listingsMessageListener" queue-names="${prosper.listing.phl.queue}" />
    <rabbit:listener ref="prospectsMessageListener" queue-names="${prosper.prospect.phl.queue}" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

---

```
public class DLQMessageRecoverer implements MessageRecoverer { 

     @Override public void recover(Message message, Throwable cause) { 
         message.getMessageProperties()
                .setHeader("error",cause.getMessage()); 
         throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(cause); 
     } 

}
```

Comment: Add that to your question, editing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set `spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.enabled` property `true`. By default RabbitMQ doesn't retry a failed message (assuming fail is on the consumer side).

Also `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` is preventing your message from being requeued.